# Views Data export gives AJAX error on batch exporting

Tags: importing-exporting

I am trying to use Views Data export to export an XLS in Batch mode, and I get this error:

> Building export
>
> Export has encountered an error.
> Please continue to the error page
>
> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: /batch?id=558&op=do StatusText: OK ResponseText:

This is the error : .OriginalPDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 The size of BLOB/TEXT data inserted in one transaction is greater than 10% of redo log size. Increase the redo log size using innodb_log_file_size

Comment: This error is too broad, so without necessary details, your question is not answerable. Check your watchdog logs for further details and provide as many clues as you can.

Comment: Can you see any error messages in your error log (`admin/reports/dblog` if you have dblog module enabled)

Comment: thank you , I enabled errors and now I can see the error

Comment: it looks like the answer is here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html

Comment: Hi Diana,
It would be helpful if you could explain how you arrived at this solution because I cannot understand how is this related to Views Data export. Thanking you in advance,
Regards,
Supriya Rajgopal

Comment: Because that is the message I get when I do the export

Comment: Since the export is happening within a batch, the data has to be stored somewhere. And per the usual Drupal is storing the information in a blob field. If I'm reading this properly, the blob field is growing and growing to the point where it's size is >10% of the redo log size for InnoDB. If your export file is >300KB, then this is very likely.